# jquery click a link programmatically

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

I know the following function to trigger click:

```
var link = $("#linkId");
    link.click();
```

but in my case I don`t have id, but I have name attribute, so I used:

```
var link = $('a[name=content_'+params['p']+']');
link.click();
```

But it is not clicking, what is the problem with the code above. if I use id it works fine.

Comment: Your selector might be incorrect. Make sure the result of `'a[name=content_'+params['p']+']'` refers to an existing element. Also, calling `.click` will only execute the event handlers, it will not make the browser follow that link.

Comment: @FelixKling Only because jQuery has a special condition on not calling the native method `.click()` specifically on `a` elements. http://jsfiddle.net/HB6X5/5/ :P It does call it on other types of element (the native .click() method) if the default action wasn't prevented and the target element has the native method.

Comment: @Esailija: Ha, learned something new :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you actually have a click event bound to the matching link. If so...

With attribute selectors, if the value is anything more complex than a sequence of letters (e.g. includes underscores or other punctuation chars), enclose it in quotes.

```
var link = $('a[name="content_'+params['p']+'"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger a click to an anchor tag by program until you bind `click` event to that.

You can do:

```
var link = $('a[name="content_'+params['p']+'"]'); // change the selector with encloses quote
link.click(function() {
  // do  something
});
```

Then trigger that click event by:

```
link.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are getting the element by your selector try to debug it
`$("[attributename='value']")` will you give you the correct element